# AngularJS Service Passing Value

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Service:

```
app.factory("MessageService", ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
  return function(message) {

    $timeout(function() {
        //    $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true;
        console.log("Test");
    }, 2000);

    return message;
  }
}]);
```

Code in Controller:

```
var message = {
      type: "success",
      title: "Message Title",
      content: "Message Content"
    }
$scope.model = MessageService(message);
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="AccountCtrl" ng-cloak="">
  <div class="ui {{model.type}} message message-overwrite"
       ng-class="{'fade': fadeMessageSuccess} ">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
      {{model.title}}
    </div>
    <p>{{model.content}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to pass the value of `true` to `$scope.fadeMessageSuccess` inside of the controller.  Since you can't use $scope inside of a service, I'm not exactly sure how to go about passing the value inside of the `$timeout` function.

Answer (score 0):

The service isn't very useful: it takes a value as argument, and returns that value.

To execute some code after some delay, wrap this code in a function and pass it to `$timeout()`, or pass it to the `.then()` method of the promise returned by `$timeout()`.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true;
}, 2000);
```

Or

```
$timeout(angular.noop, 2000).then(function() {
    $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true;
});
```

If you really want to hide the $timeout into your own service, then make the service take a callback function just as $timeout does, or return the promise returned by the call to $timeout(), so that the controller can call `then()` on that returned promise:

```
app.factory("MessageService", ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
  return function(callback) {
    $timeout(callback, 2000);
  }
}]);

...

MessageService(function() {
    $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true;
});
```

or

```
app.factory("MessageService", ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
  return function() {
    return $timeout(angular.noop, 2000);
  }
}]);

...

MessageService().then(function() {
    $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true;
});
```

Comment: This halfway works.  The timeout is working correctly but it's passing the 'message' values with the 2000ms timeout.  I need the values passed instantly, and the $scope.fadeMessageSuccess = true to be the only part with a timeout.

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing with the message. I don't have any message in my answer, because I haven't understood the point of passing a message to a service that would return it immediately. Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to pass the type, title and content straight to the $scope and then after 2 seconds, trigger the fadeMessageSuccess.

Comment: So just do `$scope.message = { type: ..., title: ..., content: ...}`. Why would you need a service to do that?

Comment: fail to see how it's harder to do `$scope.model = ...;` than to do `var message = ...;`